# Return grouped query results (C# Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to Asp.Net so this might be obvious but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I'm trying to group data in a similar fashion to below but want to return it as a list rather than a void to the console, any ideas?

Example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

```
    public void GroupBySingleProperty()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Group by a single property in an object:");

        // Variable queryLastNames is an IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, 
        // DataClass.Student>>. 
        var queryLastNames =
            from student in students
            group student by student.LastName into newGroup
            orderby newGroup.Key
            select newGroup;

        foreach (var nameGroup in queryLastNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", nameGroup.Key);
            foreach (var student in nameGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", student.LastName, student.FirstName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:

To try understand what I'm aiming to achieve I currently have

```
public IList<Application> GetGroupedApplication(string userId)
        {
            IQueryable<Application> _application;
            _application = from application
                           in _context.Application
                           where application.UserId == userId
                           select application;
            return _application.ToList<Application>();
        }
```

This is being used to create a strongly typed view of Application for the list from this query.

Application has a field called applicationOffer which I'd like to group the results by i.e.

Rejected Applications:

- Application1
- Application2

Unconditional Applications:

- Application3

Comment: What exactly do you want to return?

Comment: @DavidG ultimately I need a view (ideally of model Student) which presents the data in the same format the console does above, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of all the Console code and return the list:

```
public List<IGrouping<string,DataClass.Student>> GroupBySingleProperty()
{
    var queryLastNames =
        from student in students
        group student by student.LastName into newGroup
        orderby newGroup.Key
        select newGroup;

    return queryLastNames.ToList();
}
```

Comment: But then I can't present this in a view, I think my question was too unclear for what I'm trying to achieve, edit might help :)